# Android Eclipse Debug mode - Threads

Tags: android, eclipse, multithreading

One simple question, I was debugging my application today and for first time I asked myself a question. In Eclipse Debug Mode you have lot's of options and values, but one of the view made me think a little bit while debugging. All these `Threads` on the picture, what should they mean? Threads which are running on my application? Threads which I am starting / stopping or they are more like on system level, which controls my app. Is it normal to have that much threads or I am doing something wrong?

[image: Threads]

Thanks a lot for any kind of information / help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are all the threads which reside within your VM instance. It's normal to have more than one running or waiting at any given time during runtime. Whenever you spawn a job or a timer, a thread is created, or taken from a pool. In your screenshot, a lot of probably idle pool threads are visible as well. 
Also, think of UI programming - the Display thread is usually a standalone thread on which events are invoked by other, non-UI-threads because long-running operations on the UI-thread would appear to freeze the application as a whole.

EDIT:
To clarify, not all of those threads are conciously invoked by you. Some are started by the VM itself, some by some framework or library you might be using, and some by you - amongst which the often so-called "Main" thread is the most prominent.

EDIT2: 
You can also - at any time - pause a given thread in the Debug view and examine its current stack trace. This might give you clues as to what all those threads are doing. Chances are, they are waiting on an object (curtesy of some pool dispatcher) or polling on an empty blocking queue or something like that.

Best regards,
h.